# Automating Speed Tests on Merging Pull Requests

Tags: jenkins, automation, jmeter, performance-testing, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to track the page speed of certain urls of my project on each merging of the pull requests in Github and output the results of report in HTML format or JSON file. On the CI side, I am going to use Jenkins. I have no prior knowledge on performance testing. I want to know about the best approach to automate the speed test, integrate it with Jenkins and output the result.

On researching over the internet, I noted few possibilities which could be done to achieve this goal.

1. Installing "Page Speed Insights (psi) node package", creating the script that uses the psi for fetching the speed of certain pages, generating the test reports for use with Jenkins. (Referred to [this](https://www.oxagile.com/article/psi-automation/) link by Oxagile)
2. Performance testing using Jmeter and integrating with Jenkins.
3. Performance analysis using LightHouse. (Referred to [this](https://kitconcept.com/blog/continuous-performance-analysis-with-lighthouse-and-jenkins/) link by Timo Stollenwerk)

Choosing the right approach is very important. Therefore, I would be very grateful if anyone can suggest me different approaches and thus the right one to use(with examples if possible)in my case to achieve this goal.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, I found out that [sitespeed.io](https://www.sitespeed.io) is the best solution for achieving this goal. It is a complete web performance tool that helps us to measure the performance of the website. It is best for running in the continuous integration to find web performance regressions on commits and monitoring them in production and alerting on regressions.